# base_url not wot working in codeigniter x2 using hmvc

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I'm using Codeigniter 2 configured with hmvc everything was working fine. But for some strange reason the `base_url()` is not working when trying to use it keeps taking me to page not found. If I place the relative path to direct me to where I want to go it takes me there but not with the base_url.

If I create a test function and `echo` out the `base_url` it prints to the screen the `base_url`

I have the url helper loaded in autoload file within config 
also if I load the url helper manually at the top of the html page the `base_url()` function still does not work

Is there any things that can be causing it not to work? It was working perfectly fine on localhost but stopped working for some strange reason.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your config.php file ? 
base_url there should stil being the one you had on your localhost

```
$config['base_url']
```

you can avoid this with this little trick

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1'){
    $config['base_url'] = 'yourlocaladdress.local'; 
}else{
    $config['base_url'] = 'yourproduction.com';
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your response unfortunately it has not worked i can see what your code should do however  on chrome console tools it says my js and css files are not found  and highlighted in red  these are being called in by the base_url()

Comment: have you tried doing this ? `$this->config->item('base_url')`

Comment: Enable shorten URL from config @chris-keenan. And load URL library

Comment: thanks for all the comments guys the simple mistake was  to put a / at the end of the path name    $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/myfolder/'